# DTO object design

Tags: design-patterns, des

I have customer object contains his contact information,transaction details,address details.

Here how to design my DTO object to hold all the information.I am getting output as xml file.Here i want to map xml to dto object automatically.

Please give me any suggestions.

Regards,
Chaitu

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't really understand the question. You already have (and need) a model object.

Comment: @Franco:I dont have dto object with me.if you have any hints,please help me.

Comment: What DTO object do you exactly need? How would you call it? Contact information, transaction details and address details should be considered as separate entities while you have them in one.

Maybe show us the structure of the XML (can you possibly modify it or it is given as-is?) so we could have a notion what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have enough details to give you a proper answer but I’ll try to give it a go. For what I have understood you need to map the customers details (XML based) to a kind of DTO object. I think a good solution could be deserialize  the customer XML to the DTO object you need to create. Have a look at

http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/quick-tip-deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c

http://www.codingday.com/xml-c-class-generator-for-c-using-xsd-for-deserialization/